# Select from a comma separated list in a colum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, Table 1,

[image: Table1]

and I want to select all regions that are neighbours of region 3. What would be my query for this? The NEIGHBOUR column is a CHAR column.

I know the table should not be set up this way, but that is what I have to work with, as I don't have the rights to the database.

Comment: Show the results that you want.

Comment: More precisely, I'd like to return the names of the regions that are neigbours of a given region. In pseudo SQL, something like SELECT t.name from t where t.id_region IN t.neighbour of t.ID_REGION 3.

Comment: The main problem is that t.neighbour is a string while t.id_region is an integer, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Fix your data model!  There are numerous reasons why this is broken.

But if you ware stuck with it, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where ',' + neighbor + ',' like '%,3,%';
```

You can also unnest the value using `string_split()`:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.neighbor, ',') s
where s.value = '3';
```

Comment: That won't returns the neighbors of region 3 Gordon. The OP want to returns all the regions which 're neighbors of region 3.

Comment: @Sami . . . In English, "neighbor" is a transitive relationship -- I am my neighbor's neighbor.  This seems like the most sensible interpretation of the question, but of course the OP can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT()` as

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE Region IN 
(
  SELECT Value 
  FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT Neighbor FROM Data WHERE Region = 3), ',')
);
```

The query 'll returns 0 rows because there is no region in the table marked as a neighbor for region 3.

If you change `(3, 'Name3', '5,8,12'),` to `(3, 'Name3', '1,2'),`, then it'll returns the regions 1 and 2 because they 're neighbors of region 3.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbd9a170ce4db7010a93db385d6ba0e0).

---

Another way without using a string splitter

```
SELECT *
FROM Data D
JOIN (VALUES((SELECT Neighbor FROM Data WHERE Region = 3))) T(V)
ON CONCAT(',', T.V, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', D.Region,',%');
```

Comment: Looks like I cannot use string_split. I guess the SQL Server is older than 2016.

Comment: Then use **[`Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function)** @TheJakester